# How to transplant pgm_read_byte inside Arduino to other systems?

Tags: arduino, avr, progmem

Everyone.

I am using Renesas RA series MCU,

How to transplant pgm_read_byte()?

Can someone teach me?

Thankyou so much.=]

Comment: Just making a `constexpr` or `const` static or global variable might make it automatically read-only and in the `.rodata` section of memory (a subset of the `text` section) negating the need for [PROGMEM](https://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/pgmspace.html) special read and write functions entirely. [STM32 does this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/523439/26234).

Comment: If you're using a Renesas mcu, why did you add the `stm32` tag to this question?

Answer (score 0):

> How to transplant `pgm_read_byte()`?

The data is already `const` and / or `constexpr`. For sources that are compatible across non-AVR targets, you would:

```cpp
#if defined __AVR__ && defined __GNUC__
#include <avr/pgmspace.h>
#else // not avr-gcc
#define PROGMEM /* empty */
#define pgm_read_byte(x) (*(x))
#define pgm_read_word(x) (*(x))
#define pgm_read_dword(x) (*(x))
#define pgm_read_float(x) (*(x))
...
#endif
```

Or, if it need not be cross-target compatible, just do vanilla C/C++ and

- Drop `#include <avr/pgmspace.h>`.
- Drop `PROGMEM`.
- Replace any `pgm_read_xxx(&var)` my just accessing `var` directly.